# Bootstrap dropdown in navbar with AngularJS & Jade

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pug, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS and Jade with angular-ui-bootstrap to create a dropdown menu within the main navigation, it works perfectly with a wide screen however the problem occurs when on mobile and you have to toggle the menu!

When you click on one of the menu items the navbar closes, so clicking something within the submenu isnt possible!

Mobile Menu (without dropdown Toggled)
[image: Mobile Menu Screenshot]

Normal Menu
[image: Normal Menu Screenshot]

How the mobile menu *should* look after clicking the dropdown (but the whole menu just closes when you click it)
[image: How it should look]

The Code:

```
button.navbar-toggle(type='button', ng-click='isCollapsed = !isCollapsed')
  span.icon-bar
  span.icon-bar
  span.icon-bar
.navbar-collapse(ng-class='{collapse: isCollapsed}', ng-init='isCollapsed = true', ng-click='isCollapsed = true') 
  ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li: a(href='/#/') item1
    li: a(href='/#/') item2
    li(uib-dropdown=true,dropdown-append-to-body=false)
      a(href=true,uib-dropdown-toggle=true) Dropdown
      ul.uib-dropdown-menu
        li: a(href='#/') Item 1
        li: a(href='#/') Item 2
    li: a(href='/#/') item3
    li: a(href='/#/') item4
```

How can i get it so when i click on the dropdown within the menu it doesnt close the whole thing and instead shows the dropdown?

Comment: Do you have a plnkr or codepen for this? Or could you show the parent elements for this button and .navbar-collapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it would be best to move the `ng-click` expressions and find them a safe home in this views Controller. `ng-init` is only needed in very specific cases plus it clutters up your DOM.

```
$scope.isCollapsed = true;

$scope.toggleCollapseState = function($event) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed;
}

// DOM
button.navbar-toggle(type='button', ng-click='toggleCollapseState')
```

In regards to your toggling issue. It appears that there is a `ng-click` attribute which accepts an expression (in this case you want to use a function) that you can attach to the element that has `uib-dropdown-toggle` on it.

```
li(uib-dropdown=true,dropdown-append-to-body=false)
  a(href=true,uib-dropdown-toggle=true ng-click='navListDropdownToggled') Dropdown
```

You can then take the `$event` local that ng-click passes to the expression to stop propagation to the parent element(s).

```
$scope.navListDropdownToggled = function navListDropdownToggledFn($event) {
  $event.stopPropagation();

  // If you need to handle any toggle state-based logic 
  // you can do it by altering the isCollapsed variable.
  // $scope.isCollapsed = true;  
}
```

#### EDIT:

According to [Bootstraps Documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown), there is also an `on-toggle` attribute that passes the `$event` local as well, so this could be a more appropriate replacement for the `ng-click`.

Comment: You sir have been awarded some hefty upvotes! thanks it worked a treat! :)